# Android XML: Textview with 2 Imageviews below it that are next to each other

Tags: android, xml

I want to create a layout in Android that looks like this:

[This is  what i want the result to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfnUd.png)

So far, my code looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="216dp"
    android:layout_height="217dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

if someone could help me with this it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I suggest in this case using LinearLayout cause the layout is very simple.
Try it. Here the width of the images is halved exactly with the attribute android:layout_weight="1" in the ImageView1 and ImageView2 android:layout_weight="1", result weight is 2 (set in LinearLayout android:weightSum="2", try change it and you will see how it works).

Also, in more complex layouts, I suggest using ConstraintLayout instead RelativeLayout.

Good luck!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="40dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_marginleft="5dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Constraint layout, you won't have to nest layouts. Just define the start, end, top, and bottom constraints of each  view and then you have the layout you want. For example the two image views should have their top constrained to the bottom of the TextView, then the start of the left ImageView should be constrained to the start of parent container while the end of the right ImageView should be constrained to the end of the parent container. then constrain them against each other. i.e start of right ImageView against end of left ImageView and vice versa.